# Python Bubble Sort Working, but incorrectly?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I am fairly new to python, and was trying to make my own bubble sort recursively. While error testing, i changed the code to this:

```
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10000)

def bubbleSort(arr):
  for index in range (len(arr)-1):
    if arr[index] > arr[index+1]:
      arr[index], arr[index+1] = arr[index+1], arr[index]
      return bubbleSort(arr)


array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
array.reverse()

print(array)
sorted_array = bubbleSort(array)
print(array)
```

This initially prints a list from 99-0, and then after sorting, reverses the list, as is the idea of this algorithm. I just have no idea why this still works despite the fact that I assigned the sorted list to a new variable, printed the old variable, and it still prints a sorted list. In addition to this, I don't understand why the function doesn't return NoneType having finished sorting. Basically, my algorithm works, but I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just a tip -- you can define your array like this to avoid writing out every number manually: `array = list(range(100))`.

Comment: 1. When you `print(sorted_array)` it *is* returning `None` because you never return anything. (You return a new function evaluation call and that repeats a couple of times but at the very end it doesn't return anything, thus `None`). 2. the reason why array is modified is because you are passing it as an object and you are modifying that very object.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you understand how list works in Python.

#### Python call by reference or call by value

Python utilizes a system, which is known as “Call by Object Reference” or “Call by assignment”. In the event that you pass arguments like whole numbers, strings or tuples to a function, the passing is like call-by-value because you can not change the value of the immutable objects being passed to the function. Whereas passing mutable objects can be considered as call by reference because when their values are changed inside the function, then it will also be reflected outside the function.

```
Example 1:

# Python code to demonstrate  
# call by value 

string = "Geeks"
def test(string):
    string = "GeeksforGeeks"
    print("Inside Function:", string) 

      
# Driver's code 
test(string) 
print("Outside Function:", string)
```

#### output-1

```
Inside Function: GeeksforGeeks
Outside Function: Geeks
```

```
Example 2
   
# Python code to demonstrate  
# call by reference 
def add_more(list): 
    list.append(50) 
    print("Inside Function", list) 

# Driver's code 

mylist = [10,20,30,40] 
add_more(mylist) 
print("Outside Function:", mylist)
```

#### Output-2

```
Inside Function [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Outside Function: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```